# Is it possible to translate the suffix of an integer field?

Tags: 7, views, entities, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to translate the suffix of an integer field? The prefix/suffix settings doesn't appear under the translate section for the field. And I tried searching for the string in "Translate interface" with no luck.

The field is being used in a view where all the fields are in a list, any alternative solutions are also welcome.
Using Drupal 7.

Comment: are you using the t function? like in t('your prefix')

Comment: I'm pretty new to Drupal. I thought the t() function was only used in templates. I can use it when I edit the fields via the interface as well?

Comment: not really sure what you mean, can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Not sure that I can. I mean the problem is that there isn't an option to translate the suffix. I add the suffix through the web interface, the field is on a structure type, and when I go to edit the field, there's a input field of a suffix. But the suffix doesn't turn up in the translate option for the field nor in the general "Translate Interface".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to actually translate the suffix. Instead I added a rewrite of the field in the view where it was used, and rewrites show up in the translate settings in the view.

So the solution is, don't use a suffix. Instead add a rewrite option to the field where you use it, and translate that rewrite option instead.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7, patch #56 from https://www.drupal.org/node/1221208 allows the prefix and suffix to be translated through the regular translate interface.